# Let G be an abelian group and fix a prime p. Prove that G/P has no element of order p.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and fix a prime $p$. Let $P=\{g\in G|\operatorname{ord}(g) \text{ is a power of }p \}$.  Let's assume that $P$ is a subgroup of $G$.  Prove that $G/P$ has no element of order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\overline{x} \in G/P$ has order $p$, then $x^p \in P$, whence $x^p$ has order $p^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Hence, $O(x)$ is itself a power of $p$, and so $x\in P$.

So $\overline{x} = \overline{e}$ - a contradiction.

Comment: I am assuming that for the contradiction, it is that because it is the identity, which has order 0 which obviously does not equal p^k.

Comment: Yes, the identity has order $1\neq p$